# shell process and compare array element

Tags: shell, scripting

There is a file called test.txt that contains:

```
ljlkfjdslkfldjfdsajflkjf  word:test1
dflkdjflkdfdjls word:test2
dlkdj word:test3
word:test4
word:NewYork
dljfldflkdflkdjf word:test7
djfkd word:young
dkjflke word:lisa
amazonwle word:NewYork
dlksldjf word:test10
```

Now all we want is to get the strings after colon and if the result is same, print the output, in this case it is "NewYork"

Here is the script which lists the elements but when tried to push into array and compare it is failing, Please let me know my mistakes.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
input="test.txt"
cat $input | while read line; do output= $(echo $line | cut -d":" -f2);  done
for (( i = 0 ; i < "${#output[@]}" ; i++ ))
{
      echo ${output[i]}
}
```

Error obtained:

```
./compare.sh
./compare.sh: line 11: test1: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: test2: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: test3: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: test4: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: NewYork: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: raghav: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: young: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: lisa: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: NewYork: command not found
./compare.sh: line 11: test10: command not found
```

Comment: The input file looks like this:

Comment: cat test.txt
ljlkfjdslkfldjfdsajflkjf  word:test1
dflkdjflkdfdjls word:test2
dlkdj word:test3
word:test4
word:NewYork
dljfldflkdflkdjf word:kathy
djfkd word:young
dkjflke word:lisa
amazonwle word:NewYork
dlksldjf word:test10

Comment: I am not able to get the string into an array and then compare the array element and print, Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know my mistakes.

`output= $(..)` first excutes the command `$(..)` inside and grabs it's output. It then sets the variable `output` to an empty string as-if the same as `output=""` and exports the variable `output` and executes the output of `$(..)` as a command. Remove the space after `=`.

You are setting `output` on the right side of a pipe inside a subshell. The changes will not be visible outside - `output` is unset once the pipe terminates. Use redirection `while .... done < file`.

And `output` is not an array, but a normal variable. There is no `${output[i]}` (well, except `${output[0]}`) as it's not an array (and `output` is unset, as explained above). Append an element to an array `output+=("$(...)")`.

`#!/usr/bin/sh` - is invalid, `sh` may not be bash and support bash arrays. To use `bash` extension specifically use `bash` and use a shebang with `bash` - `#!/bin/bash`,

Now stylistic:

The format `for .... { ... }` is supported in bash since forever, however it's a rather undocumented syntax rather to be deprecated to be readable by people used to programming in `C`. Prefer the standard `do ... done`.

The expansions `$input` and `${output[i]}` are unquoted.

The `read` will ignore leading and trailing whitespaces and also interpret/ignore `\` backslash sequences (ie. see `-r` option to `read`).

`echo $line` will make `$line` undergo word splitting - multiple whitespaces will be replaced by a single space.

And using `cut` after `read` can be simpler written as just `read` with `IFS=:` and splitting on `read`. Also, if you're using `cut`, you could just `cut -d: -f2 file` on the whole file instead of cutting one line at a time.

Re-read basic bash introduction - notice that bash is space aware, spaces around `=` count. Read [bashfaq how to read a file field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), read about subshells and environments, read [bashfaq I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) and an introduction to bash arrays.